# Assigning IP to multiple hosts

Tags: loops, ansible

I am trying to assign a range of IP to different hosts, but first I am checking if the IP is already attributed. If it is, it gives me an error, so I would like to avoid that too(actually I can assign the IP, but can't pass that error, I am using ignore_errors: yes for now but I would like a better way). Here is part of my script:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  vars_files:
   - client2
  tasks:
   - set_fact:
       intip: "{{ intip | default([]) + [item] }}"
     loop: "{{ ansible_interfaces | map('extract',ansible_facts, 'ipv4') | select('defined') | map(attribute='address') | list }}"
     ignore_errors: yes
   - name: Check IP address
     shell:
       "ip a a '{{ start_ip|ipmath(my_idx) }}' dev spanbr"
     loop_control:
      index_var: my_idx
     when: (item == inventory_hostname )
     loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
     ignore_errors: yes
```

I am using this var file, but maybe there is a better way? (I am trying to use something like the first example, but can't get my head around to use it on every hosts)

First vars file (didn't try yet):

```yaml
client:
  - interface:
    - local_ip: 10.10.10.10
    - name: eth1 
  - interface:
    - local_ip: 10.10.10.11
    - name: eth1
```

Second file:

```yaml
interface:
  - config:
    - name: eth0 
  - config:
    - name: eth1

start_ip: 10.10.10.10
```

I can get only one interface getting the IP and ignoring the address, but as the when conditional is not a loop it only check one interface:

```
Output:
TASK [Check IP address] ************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [host2] => (item=host1)
failed: [host1] (item=host1) => {"ansible_index_var": "my_idx", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "ip a a '10.10.10.10' dev spanbr", "delta": "0:00:00.005429", "end": "2022-10-20 08:49:43.800954", "item": "host1", "msg": "non-zero return code", "my_idx": 0, "rc": 2, "start": "2022-10-20 08:49:43.795525", "stderr": "RTNETLINK answers: File exists", "stderr_lines": ["RTNETLINK answers: File exists"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
skipping: [host1] => (item=host2)
...ignoring
failed: [host2] (item=host2) => {"ansible_index_var": "my_idx", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "ip a a '10.10.10.11' dev spanbr", "delta": "0:00:00.002691", "end": "2022-10-20 07:49:43.815422", "item": "host2", "msg": "non-zero return code", "my_idx": 1, "rc": 2, "start": "2022-10-20 07:49:43.812731", "stderr": "RTNETLINK answers: File exists", "stderr_lines": ["RTNETLINK answers: File exists"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring
```

I would like to use a notify but I need to use the loop on the task itself so that may be an issue...

Any ideas please??

Here is the output of intip (set_fact) if that helps:

```
TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item=192.168.1.100)
ok: [host1] => (item=127.0.0.1)
ok: [host1] => (item=10.10.10.10)
ok: [host1] => (item=169.254.0.1)
ok: [host2] => (item=127.0.0.1)
ok: [host2] => (item=10.10.10.11)
ok: [host2] => (item=192.168.1.101)
```

Comment: you may want to edit your question and add this to it for sane formatting

Comment: Knowing that `set_fact` returns `ok` does not really help for anything. What will help (you in first place) is to debug the content of the variable to make sure it contains exactly what you expect

Comment: Yes it does, the variable intip returns a list of IPs I need but I don't know how to assign each one to the correct host, considering I am already using a loop on the task:

ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": [
        "192.168.1.100",
        "169.254.0.1",
        "10.10.10.10",
        "127.0.0.1"
    ]
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": [
        "127.0.0.1",
        "10.10.10.11",
        "192.168.1.101"
    ]
}

Comment: I would guess that in the end what would help me is, how to pass different variables to different hosts within the same task?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a way to do it, by using host_vars and group_vars, and making my script even easier to write :

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - set_fact:
       intip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"
   - name: Check IP address
     shell:
       "ip a a '{{ local_ip }}' dev spanbr"
     when: local_ip not in intip
```

Just by creating 2 files in host_vars.
host1.yaml:

```
ansible_host: "some_ip"
local_ip: 10.10.10.10
```

and the same for host2.yaml with different values. All is working great and it's making the script much easier to read too.